# list.Count component not updated when list changes in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Basically i have a component which has a text. This text will change depending on what all other components are doing.

```
MainPage  
..|---> Text Component  
..|---> Sibling  
...........|--> Child Of sibling 1  
...........|--> Child Of sibling 2
```

I mapped a collection of childs to each Sibling.

The text component basically just displays:

```
var s = listOfChilds.CountSomeSettings() + " is alot";
```

So the thing is whenenver i change some stuff in my listOfChilds this text component is NOT changing at all. It makes sense, but how can i "notify" my Text Component to rerender itself, because the collection changed?

I tried to have a general _manager which just has the text:

```
//TextComponent
<p>@_manager.ComputedText</p>
```

But even if i change the text in my sibling, this text is not changed in my TextComponent

Can you help me here?

Comment: Could you please provide more code? A stripped down version of your markup would be useful to fully understand.

Answer (score 4):

After you've made a change to the data, you need to call `this.StateHasChanged();` to notify the UI of the changes made.

Comment: yes but i change the data inside sibling and not inside text component.

Comment: Gotcha, so if I see this right you have your main page, which has a custom text component, and also has another component which houses individual items from the list, right? If so then you'll need to add an event handler, and call it when the data in the children change. Then in your main page, you subscribe to this event, make sure the data has changed, and then call statehaschanged, which should automatically update the textcomponent. See here under "User-defined Event": https://www.webassemblyman.com/blazor/blazorevents.html

Comment: Also look into two way data binding: https://learn-blazor.com/pages/data-binding/

Comment: learn-blazor is not maintained anymore and is extremely out of date. I've got an up to date post on Blazor binding https://chrissainty.com/blazor-bites-data-binding-and-events/